# integrity of copy function in php

Tags: php, copy, md5, md5sum

I have an app that ingests photos from SD cards. After they are copied the cards will be reformatted and put back in cameras and more photos will be stored on them.

Currently, instead of using the PHP `copy()` function, I am doing the following (roughly):

```
$card = '/Volumes/SD_Card/DCIM/EOS/';
$files = scandir($card);
$target = '/Volumes/HARD_DRIVE/photos/';

foreach($files as $k => $file) {
    if( strtolower ( pathinfo($file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION) ) == 'jpg') {
        $img_data = file_get_contents($file);
        $orig_md5 = md5($img_data);

        $success = file_put_contents($target . $file, $img_data);
        unset ($img_data);

        if( $success != TRUE ) {
            echo "an error occurred copying $file\n"; exit;
        } elseif ( $orig_md5 != md5_file($target . $file) ) {
            echo "an error occurred confirming data of $file\n"; exit;
        } else {
            echo "$file copied successfully.\n";
            unlink ($img_data);
        }
    }
}
```

I am currently doing it this way so I can compare the md5 hashes to make sure the copy is a bit-for-bit match of the original.

My questions are:

1) Would using php `copy()` be faster? I assume it would, because the target file doesn't have to be read into memory to check the md5 hash.

2) Does `copy()` do some sort of hash check as part of the function, to ensure the integrity of the copy, before returning `TRUE`/`FALSE`?

Comment: You could also use [rename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) to move/delete it in 1 go, why do you think the functions are not reliable?

Answer (score 2):

PHP's copy function would not only be faster, but does it using buffers to avoid reading all the previous file in memory, which is a problem for big files. The return boolean is only for success writing, you can rely on that, but if you want to check the hash use `md5_file` instead of passing the content into `md5`, because it is optimized in the same memory-optimized way.

However if you have just to rename the file then `rename` is far better, it is totally instant and reliable.

Comment: would `rename()` be instant between volumes - from an external disk (SD Card) to an internal hard drive?

Comment: No rename is more like Linux move command. In the same HDD it is instant. In other devices it is the same thing as copy.

Answer (score 2):

No, `copy()` doesn't perform any additional integrity checks, it assumes that the operating system's filesystem API is reliable.

You could use `md5_file()` on both the source and destination:

```
if (copy($source, $dest) && md5_file($dest) == md5_file($source)) {
    echo "File copied successfully";
} else {
    echo "Copy failed";
}
```

Note that your integrity che
cks do not actually check the the file was written to disk properly. Most operating systems use a unified buffer cache, so when you call `md5_file()` immediately after writing the file, it will get the file contents from the kernel buffers, not the disk. In fact, it's possible that the target file hasn't even been written to disk yet, it's still sitting in kernel buffers that are waiting to be flushed. PHP doesn't have a function to call [`sync(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sync), but even if it did, it would still read from the buffer cache rather than re-reading from disk.

So you're basically at the mercy of the OS and hardware, which you must assume is reliable. Applications that need more reliability tests must perform direct device I/O rather than going through the filesystem.

Comment: So as a practical point, if I understand your comment correctly, I can be no more confident in the result of the code I've written than if I just used `copy()`, and I am sacrificing performance and several lines of code, right?

Comment: Also, I assume that storing the output of `md5_file()` from the original file, then using `copy()` -- and then some time later comparing the original md5 to the output of `md5_file()` from the copied file would be a more reliable integrity check - because as you mentioned it may take some time for the OS to write the data to disk?

Comment: Probably, but you can never be sure when the data has been pushed out of cache by other processes that need the memory.

Comment: If you really need high integrity, the way to ensure it is with RAID disks, not checks in software.